# Inflate rows dynamically but strange behavior when the orientation of the device is changed

Tags: android, android-tablelayout, android-orientation

I'm trying to inflate my rows dynamically but when I change the orientation of the tablet, I get everything unselected and the checkbox name is filled with the information of the last row. For example, supose I have two checkboxes (two rows) the first one says "hello" and the second says "good bye". If I rotate the tablet I get the first and second checkbox with the name "good bye" and everything unselected.

```
<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tableLayoutList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 

</ScrollView>
```

I have my row defined like this (mRowLayout.xml):

```
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutRow"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxServEmail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</TableRow>
```

And then I use the following code to inflate my row:

```
private void fillTable(View v, Cursor c) {

TableLayout ll = (TableLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.tableLayoutList);

View mTableRow = null;
int i = 0;
while(!c.isAfterLast()){
    i++;
    mTableRow = (TableRow) View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.mRowLayout, null);

     CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)mTableRow.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxServEmail);

             Log.e("debugging", "email: "+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Serv.EMAIL)));
     cb.setText( c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Serv.EMAIL)));


     mTableRow.setTag(i);

    //add TableRows to TableLayout
    ll.addView(mTableRow);

    c.moveToNext();
}
}
```

Does anyone knows why do I have this strange behavior?. Also notice that I put a Log.e for print in my log cat whats going on. And I get "hello" and "good bye" every time I change the orientation of my device, but the setText doesnt seem to work properly.

Please help, I have been with this issue for hours and I don't get it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The activity is destroyed and recreated when you change device orientation. You should use the

```
onSaveInstanceState
```

callback to save your current UI data. And use onCreate to restore it:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {

    // first run

} else {

    // not first run

}
```

Comment: I know about this, for the check selections you are right but what about the setText of the check box. Why it doesnt work properly?. If the view is recreated, it should show me "hello", "good bye" no matter what I do with the orientation.

Comment: Are you restoring the state from savedInstanceState? You should, because that's what it's for. You should only use the cursor if it's the first run or something is changed in your scroll view.

Comment: Save an array of strings that represent text in checkboxes. Also save a synchronous array of booleans that will represent whether the checkboxes have been selected (true) or not. 
Then in onCreate, retrieve these values from saveInstanceState

Comment: I just did it and it worked. You are absolutely right!!. Thank you so much :).